# Standart dialog button style to JFoenix

Tags: java, css, javafx, dialog, jfoenix

I'm making javafx application and using Jfoenix library.

Window with specific information about item from table opens by this code:

```
@FXML
public void showEditPolicyDialog() {
    Policy selectedPolicy = policyTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int selectedPolicyIndex = policyTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

    if (selectedPolicy == null) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("No Policy Selected");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Please select Policy you want to edit.");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
    } else {
        selectedPolicy = Datasource.getInstance().getFullPolicyById(selectedPolicy.getId());
    }

    Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();

    dialog.initOwner(mainWindowAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow());
    dialog.setTitle("Edit policy " + selectedPolicy.getNumber());
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/ee/insa/views/PolicyDialogLayout.fxml"));

    try {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't load edit policy dialog");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);

    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
    okButton.setDefaultButton(false);

    dialog.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("ee/insa/CSS/PolicyWindowCSS.css");

    PolicyController policyController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    Policy fullPolicy = Datasource.getInstance().getFullPolicyById(selectedPolicy.getId());
    policyController.loadPolicyDataToForm(fullPolicy);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();

    if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        policyController.updatePolicyData(fullPolicy);
        Datasource.getInstance().updatePolicy(fullPolicy);
        Policy updatedPolicyForMainTable = Datasource.getInstance().getPolicyForMainTableById(fullPolicy.getId());
        policyTable.getItems().set(selectedPolicyIndex, updatedPolicyForMainTable);
        policyTable.getSelectionModel().select(selectedPolicyIndex);
        if (inClientSearch == false) {
            checkTableView();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i set Dialog button style to JFoenix? Now buttons have standart Windows style.
[image]

In CSS i can find area, where buttons are (pink color):

```
.dialog-pane > .button-bar > .container {
    -fx-background-color: deeppink;
}
```

But I can't find exact those 2 buttons. If I start to style by

```
.dialog-pane > .button {
     -fx-background-color: deeppink;
}
```

then ALL buttons are restyled.

UPDATED:
I tried to implement JFXDialog by this code:

```
    @FXML
public void showEditPolicyDialog(){
    Policy selectedPolicy = policyTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    selectedPolicy = Datasource.getInstance().getFullPolicyById(selectedPolicy.getId());

    try {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ee/insa/views/PolicyDialogLayout.fxml"));
        JFXDialogLayout dialogLayout = new JFXDialogLayout();
        dialogLayout.setBody(parent);
        JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog( mainWindowStackPane, dialogLayout, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.BOTTOM);
        dialog.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but problem is that it is not separate window, it show only in space of main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. Using this code

```
for(ButtonType bt : dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes()){
        Button button = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(bt);
        button.getStyleClass().add("dialogButton");
}
```

i can apply CSS class only to those 2 buttons.

```
.dialogButton {
-fx-background-color: -fx-primary;
-fx-text-fill: -fx-primatytext;
-fx-font-size: 12pt;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
-fx-border-width: 1px;
-fx-border-color: -fx-secondary;
}
.dialogButton:hover {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary;
}
```

Now it looks fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JFoenix `JFXDialog` instead of the default JavaFX `Dialog:

```
JFXDialog<ButtonType> dialog = new JFXDialog<>();
```